# The meaning of 似つかわしくない

Tags: translation, meaning

> 呼び出し場所は、昼休み中には**似つかわしくない**通学路。その途中にある休憩所だ。

**似つかわしくない**: inappropriate, unsuitable.

I'm confused with the sentence, and I suspected **似つかわしくない** might have another meaning.

If I translated the sentence, it will be like:

> The meeting point is on the school route, which is **not suitable**
>   during the lunch break. It is a rest area along that route.

(sounds strange to put together the words **not suitable** with a time period like a **lunch break**)

Please kindly enlighten me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think this is actually more of a semantics issue than a translation issue.

> 昼休み中には似つかわしくない通学路
>
> school route which is unsuitable/unusual for/during lunch break

I might translate `昼休み中に` as `for lunch break` in this specific case, although in most cases `during lunch break` is definitely the obvious choice. However, the point I really want to make though is that `unusual for lunch break` is maybe not as strange as you seem to be suggesting it is, at least assuming the speaker in this case is a student.

The sentence appears to be saying that this person was called out to an "unusual" place to be during lunch break, presumably in the sense that it's not the kind of place you would expect students to be at that time. This makes sense for a school route; by definition we only expect students to be there in the morning/evening.

A much looser (but easier to understand) translation of the first sentence:

> The meeting place was on my route to school, the last place I expected to be during lunch break

Comment: I did consider the unsuitable word refers to a location for having lunch, but after I browse the words 昼休み, all the examples that I found were a lunch break period, That's why I was wondering perhaps the words 似つかわしくない have another meaning like not the same/different (In the meaning the school route itself was a different route from the school route normally passed through during the lunch break). Thank you for your tips.

Comment: I don't think this has as much to do with actually eating lunch as with 1. time of day (I.E. the middle of the day, which happens to be when lunch is eaten) and 2. it being a place to meet. (I believe l'electeur said something to this effect in a comment and then deleted it? but in any case) there are also more standard places to meet than the route to school.